# Fill Sh script values using PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I have a ready sh script to do some tasks I want, and this sh script shows a menu after execution for example :

```
Enter 1 to Select Menu 1 or 2 to select Menu 2

 1. Menu 1
 2. Menu 2
```

Then :

```
Enter a number to install X addon :

 1. Addon 1
 2. Addon 2
```

Currently, I use in my PHP script to execute the Sh script :

```
echo shell_exec('sh /etc/share/nginx/autoload-rev5.sh');
```

How can I fill the values required by the Sh script from PHP without modifying the Sh script? is it possible ?

Comment: it depends on how your script is reading the numbers

Comment: @fedorqui the script except different parameters for each menu selection, there is 9 menus, and I'm interested in only 2

Comment: @Huey the Devops who created the file is not available, I don't have enough experience to modify the whole sh file in order to start passing vars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using expect - http://php.net/manual/en/expect.examples-usage.php

This is pretty much the same as the expect Linux tool, but you are coding in PHP

You can see some more examples here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.expect-expectl.php

Basically pattern match shell output and on match, submit a predefined response

Comment: This worked for me, and gave me more flexibility to communicate with the shell file from PHP +1

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/function.proc-open.php) function.
Call it to create a handle on your script (instead of using shell_exec) then parse its output and write what you want to its input.